# How do you get your wordpress plugin content onto the fronted?

Tags: wordpress

I just started with Wordpress development and have created a very simple FAQ plugin.
To display it, I want to use some accordion style JavaScript, etc, so I need to somehow get some custom HTML onto the fronted.
Secondly, I want to end up with an "FAQ" button in the main navigation that when clicked displays all the FAQ's that were created.

What is the typical way to achieve this?
Do I add custom Templates to my plugin?
Do I create a shortcode? A widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did that stuff in a plugin, for shure you have been declared a function to print your needs, so you can call that function in a page of your template.